# Error getting records from db using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Entity class which has primary key type as UUID.

Here is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_IP", indexes = @Index(columnList = "IP"))
public class LOGIP {
    private UUID ID;
    private Long IP;
    private String COUNTRY;
    private String COUNTRYCODE;

    public LOGIP() {
    }

    public LOGIP(Long IP, String COUNTRY) {
        this.ID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(String.valueOf(IP).getBytes());
        this.IP = IP;
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false)
    public UUID getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(UUID ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IP")
    public Long getIP() {
        return IP;
    }

    public void setIP(Long IP) {
        this.IP = IP;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    public String getCOUNTRY() {
        return COUNTRY;
    }

    public void setCOUNTRY(String COUNTRY) {
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        LOGIP logip = (LOGIP) o;
        return Objects.equals(IP, logip.IP);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(IP);
    }
}
```

I am trying query data by specific id. For specific UUID's I can't retrieve data.

First I have tested by querying all data in db and checked in runtime for the specific UUID. And found entries are retrieved by query. Below is the code for that. It prints the records associated with those three ID's mentioned below.

```
String name = LOGIP.class.getName();
Query<LOGIP> query = session.createQuery("from " + name , LOGIP.class);
List<LOGIP> list = query.list();

for (LOGIP logip : list) {
    if (logip.getID().equals(UUID.fromString("4247D43F-4EF3-33C1-A9BC-3902E18DF1F7")) || logip.getID().equals(UUID.fromString("73B0AFE5-A54D-3130-868E-A5D2040A8A20")) ||logip.getID().equals(UUID.fromString("F94F32A3-A6B2-34C5-8B18-23C84964AB20"))) {
           System.out.println("logip = " + logip);
       }
}
```

If I try to query by setting parameters, query returns empty list.

```
// This ID Returns record associated with it when queried by parameter
query.setParameter("id", UUID.fromString("4247D43F-4EF3-33C1-A9BC-3902E18DF1F7")); 

// Below ID's returns empty list when queried by parameter
query.setParameter("id", UUID.fromString("73B0AFE5-A54D-3130-868E-A5D2040A8A20")); 
query.setParameter("id", UUID.fromString("f94f32a3-a6b2-34c5-8b18-23c84964ab20"));
```